# react-native drawer with navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigator, drawer

i'm having problem with drawer and navigator

https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer

the problem is when i press any button on the drawer with callback for push another view it goes Extremely slow
here is my code

```
    render() {
    return <Navigator
        ref={(nav) => { navigator = nav; }}
        initialRoute={{name:'PlayingNow'}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={(route, routeStack) => ({
            ...route.sceneConfig || Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight,
            gestures: route.gestures
        })}
        sceneStyle={{backgroundColor:'#F5FCFF'}}
    />
}

renderScene(route, navigator){
    let Component = ROUTES[route.name];
    return(
            <Drawer
                type="overlay"
                content={<DrawerContent route={route} navigator={navigator}/>}
                tapToClose={true}
                panOpenMask={0.1}
                openDrawerOffset={0.25} // 20% gap on the right side of drawer
                panCloseMask={0.2}
                closedDrawerOffset={0}
                tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({
                    main: { opacity:(2-ratio)/2 }
                })}
            >
                <Component route={route} navigator={navigator}/>
            </Drawer>

        )

}
```

i tried to move the navigator inside the drawer but i lost the reference for navigator and it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function that returns navigator function like this :

```
getNav()
{
  return this._navigator
}
```

//inside renderscene

```
renderscene(route,navigator)
{
  this._navigator = navigator
}
```

call getNav function while passing navigator reference.

Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

Bind this with renderScene

```
renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
```